# Cannot download "Office 365" because it is not compatible with Samsung Galaxy Tab S2

Tags: google-play-store, ms-office, samsung-galaxy-tab-s-2

I have Office on my Samsung Galaxy Tab S2, but I cannot upgrade it to Office 365. I can't download it from Google Play Store because it tells me that

> Your device isn't compatible with this version.

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

This is a high-end tablet, so I expected it to be compatible.

Is Microsoft still going to support this issue out, or do I, in fact, already have 365 without knowing it?

Comment: Your device isn't compatible with the application you want to download

Answer (score 0):

Based on my memory and [this article](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/microsoft-took-android-x-awesome-android-apps-made-microsoft/), there was an old "Microsoft Office" app that was replaced by individual Microsoft Office apps:

- [Microsoft Word](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.office.word)
- [Microsoft Excel](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.office.excel)
- [Microsoft PowerPoint](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.office.powerpoint)
- and [more...](https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=6720847872553662727)

However, there are *no* "Office 365" apps. ["Office 365"](https://products.office.com/en/mobile/office) is a subscription plan that enhances the user experience of individual Office apps with advanced mobile features.

---

For this particular case:

Samsung Galaxy Tab S2 was deemed as "not compatible" by Play Store. The exact reason cannot be known because there are too many possibilities. However, the download is only prevented on the Play Store. You can still find and download the APK file from credible 3rd-party sources (e.g. [APK Mirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/microsoft-corporation/word/)) and try to install it, and see if it's compatible (working properly).

Regarding the status of your "Office 365", that depends whether you have subscribed to it or not previously. But the migration from the old Microsoft Office app to the newer individual Office apps didn't affect the status of someone's "Office 365" subscription plan.

Answer (score -1):

The type of Office 365 subscription plan you have determines the availability of some mobile apps and what you can do on them. For a plan comparison, see:

| Home plans | Business plans | Education plans | Nonprofit plans |

The information you seek is right here => [Office 365 Mobile Setup](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Office-365-mobile-setup-Help-7dabb6cb-0046-40b6-81fe-767e0b1f014f)

Comment: I'm not sure that's the case. AFAIK, anyone should be able to download all Office 365 apps *regardless* of their subscription plan and as long as *the apps are compatible with the devices*. Microsoft and Google Play Store aren't able to limit the availability of the apps based on external limitation (e.g. Office 365 subscription plan). However, the check will be done when the Office apps are run on the device, in which Microsoft is able to check the license after login inside the app.